# Alerts signal counts are differing when compared with Strategy signals

Tags: pine-script

I tried to generate alerts based on the below-attached study. Alerts are generated but they are differing from strategy signals. Today I generated signals for TCS. According to **Strategy**, there are **5 trades today** but whereas coming to **Alerts** I got nearly **12-15 signals**. I don't know where I'm missing. If anyone knows about this please help me.

For reference, I'm attaching a snapshot

[1.Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pW0b.png)
[2.Alert Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlaRV.png)

**This is Study**

```
//@version=4
study("Study1_v4", overlay=true)
tim=input('30')
//160

isSession  = input(defval = true, title = "Apply Trading Session", type = input.bool)
sess = input(defval = "0935-1500", title="Trading Session")
t = time(timeframe.period, sess)
sessionOpen = isSession ? (na(t) ? false : true):true 
startYear   = input(defval = 2020, title = "From Year",     type = input.integer)
startMonth  = input(defval = 1,    title = "From Month",    type = input.integer )
startDay    = input(defval = 1,    title = "From Day",      type = input.integer)
endYear     = input(defval = 2112, title = "To Year",       type = input.integer)
endMonth    = input(defval = 1,    title = "To Month",      type = input.integer)
endDay      = input(defval = 1,    title = "To Day",        type = input.integer)
showDate  = input(defval = true, title = "Show Date Range", type = input.bool)
start     = timestamp(startYear, startMonth, startDay, 00, 00)        // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(endYear, endMonth, endDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false       // create function "within window of time"
longCondition = (crossover(security(syminfo.tickerid, tim, close,barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on),security(syminfo.tickerid, tim, open,barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)) and sessionOpen and window())
shortCondition = (crossunder(security(syminfo.tickerid, tim, close,barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on),security(syminfo.tickerid, tim, open,barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)) and sessionOpen and window())
val = 0
if (longCondition)
    val := 1
if (shortCondition)
    val := -1
//if(not sessionOpen)
//    val := -3
plot(val, title="type", color=color.black)

//defining plots above are required only for the purpose of passing dynamic variables to alerts. Their color is set to 'na' so that they don't display on the screen.

alertcondition(val !=0 or not sessionOpen, title='Alert', message='{{ticker}}, price = {{close}} OrderType={{plot("type")}} at time = {{time}}')
```

**This is Strategy**

```
//@version=4
strategy("Strategy1_v4", overlay=true,process_orders_on_close=true)
tim=input('30')
//160

isSession  = input(defval = true, title = "Apply Trading Session", type = input.bool)
sess = input(defval = "0935-1500", title="Trading Session")
t = time(timeframe.period, sess)
sessionOpen = isSession ? (na(t) ? false : true):true 
startYear   = input(defval = 2020, title = "From Year",     type = input.integer)
startMonth  = input(defval = 1,    title = "From Month",    type = input.integer )
startDay    = input(defval = 1,    title = "From Day",      type = input.integer)
endYear     = input(defval = 2112, title = "To Year",       type = input.integer)
endMonth    = input(defval = 1,    title = "To Month",      type = input.integer)
endDay      = input(defval = 1,    title = "To Day",        type = input.integer)
showDate  = input(defval = true, title = "Show Date Range", type = input.bool)
start     = timestamp(startYear, startMonth, startDay, 00, 00)        // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(endYear, endMonth, endDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false       // create function "within window of time"
longCondition = (crossover(security(syminfo.tickerid, tim, close,barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on),security(syminfo.tickerid, tim, open,barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)) and sessionOpen and window())
shortCondition = (crossunder(security(syminfo.tickerid, tim, close,barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on),security(syminfo.tickerid, tim, open,barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)) and sessionOpen and window())
val = 0
if (longCondition)
    val := 1
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
if (shortCondition)
    val := -1
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short)
//if(not sessionOpen)
//    val := -3
strategy.close_all(when =  not sessionOpen)
plot(val, title="type", color=color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible reasons are in pyramiding - strategy don't enter to the same position, your study - does

Comment: Thank for your response. I tried with the pyramiding to my strategy. Still, I'm getting the same problem. You can also try the above scripts

Comment: I think the problem in `not sessionOpen` condition for your alerts. Look on this https://i.imgur.com/QJzMWw5.png when `not sessionOpen` is true the strategy doesn't send orders, but your alert are fired